# Unable to access property of eloquent model query result

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, eloquent-relationship

I am encountering what I would assume to be a common issue but I have not found a relevant solution.

In my Laravel application, I have a relationship setup between two models: BarterReview and BarterReviewFeedback.

**BarterReview.php**

```
public function barterReviewFeedback () {
    return $this->hasOne(BarterReviewFeedback::class, 'barter_review_id');
}
```

**BarterReviewFeedback.php**

```
public function barterReview () {
    return $this->belongsTo(BarterReview::class);
}
```

The Following returns a `BarterReview` with the associated `BarterReviewFeedback`:

```
$review = \App\BarterReview::with('barterReviewFeedback')->find(1);
return $review;
```

The result (`$review`) looks like this when formatted:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "created_at": "2020-04-06T20:13:15.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2020-04-06T20:13:15.000000Z",
  "rating": 5,
  "comment": "Five out of Five!",
  "user_id": 2,
  "barter_id": 1,
  "barter_review_feedback": {
    "id": 3,
    "created_at": "2020-06-02T16:34:41.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-06-02T16:34:41.000000Z",
    "barter_review_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "content": "test"
  }
}
```

The ISSUE is that I am unable to access "barter_review_feedback" inside the object - `$review->barter_review_feedback` doesn't display anything.

Additionally, attempting to directly access a property inside of `$review->barter_review_feedback` such as `$review->barter_review_feedback->id` yields the following error: `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

Any ideas as to why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access relationship like this

```
$review->barterReviewFeedback->id
```

Because your relationship is `barterReviewFeedback` not `barter_review_feedback`

Comment: I can do that but doesn't that eliminate the point of using `::with('barterReviewFeedback)`? Shouldn't I be able to access the object using the key itself and not the relationship?

Comment: Change your relationship using snack_case, and you can able access relationship using key itself. `public function barterReviewFeedback () { return $this->hasOne(BarterReviewFeedback::class, 'barter_review_id'); }` to ,`public function barter_review_feedback () { return $this->hasOne(BarterReviewFeedback::class, 'barter_review_id'); }`

Comment: The relationship is already being called via `::with('barterReviewFeedback')`, I simply want to access the property on the returned `$review` object. I've never had an issue with this method before.

Comment: You can access property of object ,`$review` like this. $review->id, $review->rating, $review->comment, $review->barterReviewFeedback->id, $review->barterReviewFeedback->barter_review_id

Comment: Maybe a better question would be: What's the point of `$request = \App\BarterReview::with('barterReviewFeedback')->find(1)` when I can just use `$request = \App\BarterReview::find(1);` and then call `$request->barterReviewFeedback;` ?

Comment: The point is When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model. Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem.  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Ah! I just read that in the docs - that clears everything up. Thank you!